# Neural Net Toolbox Feed Forward Network issuing "Output <variable> Not Assigned" error when spreadsheets are used as Training and Validation data

Tags: excel, matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to create a feed forward network that can fit a set of financial data.  The financial data was supplied to us in the form of Excel spreadsheets.  I have created smaller spreadsheets that only contain the necessary data.  But when I import the training set and validation sets, then try to train the network, I get the following error when I reach the training function:

> Output argument "v" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "network/subsref".

I have checked my code over and done research, but I am unable to determine the problem.  The information I found on the error says that it meant that an output argument did not exist, but I cannot see where.

Relevant code snippets:

```
training_patterns = xlsread('Training_Set');
validation_patterns = xlsread('Validation_Set');
ndim_inputs=2; %2D patterns--not counting bias
nnodes_layer1=5; %try this many interneurons--not including bias
nnodes_layer2=1; %single output

net = feedforwardnet(5, 'trainlm');

[net, tr] = net.train(net, training_patterns, validation_patterns);
```

By the way, the matrices that contain the data are of substantial size.  The training matrix is 227x8 and the validation matrix is 51x8.

Comment: This is unrelated, but I'd like to ask a question.  What do the rows and columns of your data mean?  Do the rows denote the number of samples, or do the columns do that?  Also, what dimension describes the features?  The NN toolbox requires that each row is a feature, while each column is a sample.

Comment: The data is meant to be financial data for some companies.  Wait, each column is a sample?  The way I have my matrices set up the samples are the rows.  Maybe I have it backward.  In the spreadsheet I've been given, each company is a row, while its properties are the columns.  Edit: I tried transposing the matrices, but got the same result.

Comment: Yes, each column is supposed to be a sample... a bit backwards I'll admit. Each property is a row.  It's most likely because of the way forward propagation works. It's more natural to have your data like this.  Try using just `train` instead of `net.train`: `net = train(net, training_patterns, validation_patterns);`

Comment: That fixed the error this question addresses, so that worked!  Thank you! Now the error is: different number of samples.  That's not related to the question though.

Comment: Yes, that's because for each training point, you need a validation point.  These don't match up.  BTW, do you want me to write an answer about `train` method so you could accept it?... or should we wait until we fix this issue too? :)

Comment: Actually I just fixed that error =/  May as well write an answer.  I'd be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: Oh? How did you fix it? and I just wrote one :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen the Neural Network Toolbox being used that way.  Try using just the `train` method rather than just `net.train`:

```
net = train(net, training_patterns, validation_patterns);
```

Comment: Remember the bit about how I transposed the matrices?  I commented that out and it worked.  I figured I'd answer that question here.  The site was beginning to complain about our discussion =D